# Deciding whether a complex function has a primitive in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to decide whether $g(z)=\bar{z}$ has a primitive in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. I'm struggling to decide where to start. I was thinking of using Cauchy's integral theorem i.e. if $g(z)$ is holomorphic then $$\int_C g(z) \: \text{d}z=0,$$ where $C$ is a closed path. But I'm really not sure. Some tips would be great!

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)$ has a primitive $F(z)$ in some open set $\Omega$, then $f$ must be holomorphic on $\Omega$ because the derivative of a holomorphic function is holomorphic. But $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is not holomorphic on any non-empty open set because it doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example the unit circle with the usual parametrization:

$$C:=\{e^{it}\;:\;0\le t\le 2\pi\}\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;z=e^{it}\implies dz=ie^{it}dt$$

so your integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}ie^{it}dt=2\pi i$$

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{z}$ is not even holomorphic. Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle in the positive orientation, then
$$ \int_\gamma \overline{z}\,dz = i \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{e^{i\phi}} e^{i\phi}\,d\phi = i\int_0^{2\pi} \,d\phi = 2\pi i
$$
By Goursat's theorem, $\overline{z}$ cannot be holomorphic in the unit disk. You can expand $\gamma$ to show that $\overline{z}$ is not holomorphic in any disk.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to get at, excellent!